# IIS 7 with Windows authentication fail

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication

I have a folder on my website I want to protect with Windows authentication. The problem I get is that the prompt is re-appearing - like the credentials are not correct. But when I look in the event viewer I see an audit success.

I am using a local Windows user to authenticate.
in IIS->On the folder I have enabled Windows Authentication.
In IIS->In the folder I have allowed the user in "Authorization rules"

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score -3):

Give the passwd in the .ini file

Comment: What ini file are you talking about - where can I find this?